# What is the most "general" definition of a Euclidean space?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm finding conflicting definitions of Euclidean space. Rudin defines it specifically as the vector space $\mathbb{R}^k$ together with its standard inner product and norm structure. In other cases, I'm seeing it defined as the set of $k$-tuples in some unspecified set. Apparently, these are the same up to isomorphism, but what is the most "general" definition of Euclidean space (or spaces, since there seem to be multiples)?

Comment: As usual, the Wikipedia article [Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) has the information you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

The author will specify the definition that will be used.  Not everyone states the same definition, because not everyone has the same uses in mind.

Note the textbook Loomis and Sternberg, where Euclidean space is written $E^n$ and $n$-tuples of reals is written $R^n$.  So in this version, $R^n$ is $E^n$ together with some additional structure.  So for example, $E^n$ by itself has no distinguished point "the origin" and no distinguished lines "the axes".

Comment: Is there a specific set from which the elements of $E^n$ are taken, though? In other words, is an intuitive understanding of Euclidean space "$\mathbb{R}^n$ with some added structure"?

Comment: So $E^2$ is what we find in the first part of Euclid's *Elements*.  Nowadays we would say that points and lines are undefined concepts, governed by certain axioms.