# What is $\mathbb{E}^d$?

Tags: definition, bezier-curve

In a [paper](http://web.math.unifi.it/users/sestini/Bezier.pdf) (chapter 3, the paper is in Italian) I'm reading I found:

> A Bézier curve of degree $n$ is a parametric polynomial curve $X:[0;1]\to\mathbb{E}^d$ defined as follows:

I'm not an expert in the field and I've never seen this set "$\mathbb{E}^d$". What is it? The only thing I found online is the expected value, but I don't see how that would apply here.

Comment: Hard to say. Usually Bézier curves just map into $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Maybe you could additionaly link the paper

Comment: Can you give the source, where you get the definition?

Comment: It sometimes refers to the Euclidean space, emphasing its euclidean structure

Comment: The E probably stands for "Euclidean", so it just means $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @Meowdog I edited the question, but the paper is in Italian so I don't know if this helps.

Comment: From the context (page 12), it refers to the euclidean space $\Bbb R^d$ thought of as an affine space (i.e forgetting about the linear structure and the particular choice of an origin).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4160395/442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space in which Bezier curves describe the object does not possess a preferred coordinate system—so you have to define  yourselves. Many such systems could be picked (and some will certainly be more practical than others). But whichever one you choose, it should not affect any properties of the object itself. Our interest
is in the object and not in its relationship to some arbitrary coordinate system. Therefore, the methods one wants to develop must be independent of a particular choice of a coordinate system. We say that those methods must be coordinate-free or coordinate-independent. This geometry is called **affine geometry**. Bezier curves "live" in affine spaces, not in linear spaces. So to distinguish  $\mathbb{R}^d$ as a vector space and as an affine space, we introduce $\mathbb{E}^d$ as the affine space.